# Erro de (T_Variable) no php,como resolver?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou com um erro ao conectar no banco de dados,o php diz que não reconhece a linha.

Ele da o seguinte erro : 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$conexao' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\formcadastro\conexao2.php on line 6**

Meu código em php :

```
<?PHP
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass =  "";
$banco = "cadastrocli"
$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());


$idCad       = $_POST ['idCad'];
$nome       = $_POST ['Nome'];      
$email      = $_POST ['Email']; 
$senha      = $_POST ['Senha']; 
$confirmar  = $_POST ['Confirmar']; 
$telefone   = $_POST ['Telefone'];  
$celular    = $_POST ['Celular'];
$nascimento = $_POST ['Nascimento'];
$sexo       = $_POST ['Sexo'];
$bairro     = $_POST ['Bairro'];
$cidade     = $_POST ['Cidade'];
$estado     = $_POST ['Estado'];

$sql = mysql_query "(INSERT INTO cadastrocli (idCad, Nome, Email, Senha, Confirmar, Telefone, Celular, Nascimento, Sexo, Bairro, Cidade, Estado) 
VALUES ('$idCad', '$nome', '$email', '$senha', '$confirmar', '$telefone', '$celular', '$nascimento', '$sexo', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$estado');"
echo"Cadastro efetuado com sucesso;"            
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Colocando o `;` na linha anterior. Todas as linhas devem terminar assim para não afetar as demais, arrume isto:

```
$banco = "cadastrocli";
```

Embora não vai acontecer nada agora, é adequado fazer o mesmo na última linha. Não só porque vai acostumando sempre colocar o ponto e vírgula, mas também facilita se mais tarde colocar novas linhas, não terá o mesmo erro que ocorre agora.

Programação é ter atenção ao detalhes.

Veja ["funcionando" no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/smjtWF). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/QuerySyntax.php). Note que não gera nenhum erro.

Comment: Então,modifiquei mas mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Comment: Editei a resposta pra mostrar que funciona. Aí o problema é outro e específico no seu ambiente. Aí não temos como saber o que ocorre. O motivo de fechamento da pergunta permanece o mesmo, porque ou é erro de digitação ou não pode ser reproduzido. Dê uma olhada se não está fazendo algo errado, se está salvando o editado no lugar certo, se o erro mudou de lugar. Se tiver outro erro, abra outra pergunta.

Comment: No Google ao tentar rodar,continua dando o mesmo erro,não é erro de digitação pois já verifiquei,o que pode ser se for é um erro nas variáveis ao serem chamadas.

Comment: Mas o google não roda código.

Comment: Era claramente erro de digitação, se tem outro problema, abra uma nova pergunta com informações suficientes para poder ajudar. A única coisa que posso acrescentar que este código está pedindo para receber um ataque e roubar e destruir o banco de dados. E não sei o que significa Google nesse contexto. Os contextos que eu conheço, não roda mesmo, não é função dele rodar código PHP. Se quer ajuda, dê informações suficientes para ser ajudado. Jogar palavras sem nexo não vai te ajudar.